# Use of template engines in Spring boot MVC

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am very new to `Spring boot` .I just started a `Spring boot MVC` application . I am planing to use `html` and `angularjs` for the view layer . I have some research on Spring boot MVC , and saw some template engine (`Thymeleaf`) . Now I am confused .
Do I need to use any of these template engine to build a `Spring boot MVC` application ? What exactly the use of these template engines ? Can I create a Spring boot MVC only with `HTML` and `angularjs` ?

Answer (score 0):

A template engine is a framework that takes some text as input and outputs some valid HTML. The text as input is something that could look like HTML plus some placeholders for the variables you want to display. It also offers many utility functions, looping capabilities, conditionals.

All these you don't get from HTML. There are varieties you can choose from:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html

If you want to take the angularjs approach, then you'll probably have to go the REST way and return JSON from the server side and then process it in your angularjs controller and display in the angularjs view.

Here's a tutorial:
https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/spring-and-angular-js-a-secure-single-page-application

Or here a more general view:

[Angularjs + spring MVC](http://blog.angular-university.io/developing-a-modern-java-8-web-app-with-spring-mvc-and-angularjs/)